# UIButton Highlighting Overcome default behaviour

Tags: ios, uibutton, highlighting

In a program much like the who want to be a millionaire... I have 4 option buttons.  It should flash red or green on press.  The four buttons have either red or green images as background images.  In the code setup I have such a method ready to setup the first question and when the second question gets set, the background images change accordingly.
Currently the default blue highlight is always appearing on the first pressing of any one the buttons and after that there are other issues.

I could paste some different approaches here, (but they dont work).  So any suggestions would be good.

Also in the IB, when you set the highlight with background image, that works.  I would use use, but for the same button, the back ground image must be changed programmatically.

Thanks in advance for the help/suggestions!

Comment: I still have a problem with it though.  For changing the background images there is a switch that doesn't seem to do the job properly:

[option_one   setBackgroundImage:wrong  forState:UIControlStateSelected ];
.
.
.

[option_one   setBackgroundImage:wrong  forState: UIControlStateHighlighted ];
.
.
.

The result at the moment is sometimes it highlights the background button correct and sometimes it just picks the other image.  I'm also using a reset method with nil as image in between to try and get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `State` `UIControlStateNormal` and  `UIControlStateHighlighted`

```
[btnMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1-Highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: unbelievable, that was it.